# Calling listener in p:selectBooleanCheckbox without refreshing the whole dataTable in Primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a `Primeface` `selectBooleanCheckbox` in a column of a DataTable. Inside there is a `<p:ajax` that on check calls the method in the listener `(mybean.checkCell(cell.field2))` and saves the status of the checkbox.
My problem is that the entire `p:dataTable` is refreshed when I check.

How do I  call `mybean.checkCell(cell.field2)` without refreshing the whole dataTable?

Here is my code:

```
 <p:dataTable var="cell" value="#{mybean.mycells}" widgetVar="cell" emptyMessage="No cells" filteredValue="#{mybean.filteredCells}">
     <p:column filterBy="#{cell.field1}" headerText="Field1" filterMatchMode="contains">
         <h:outputText value="#{cell.field1}" />
     </p:column>
     <p:column headerText="Checkbox">
         <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{cell.check}" partialSubmit="true">
             <p:ajax process="@this"  partialSubmit="true" update=":form:messages" listener="#{mybean.checkCell(cell.field2)}" onstart="PF('statusDialog').show();" oncomplete="PF('statusDialog').hide();" />
         </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
      </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: This is not the default behavior. Cause of problem is not visible in information provided so far but you can find debugging hints in http://stackoverflow.com/q/2118656

Comment: So it shouldn't do refresh the whole dataTable? If yes, maybe you have an idea about what could be wrong?

Comment: @Gyonder: read the comment by BalusC again... it requests **you** to **do** things, not ask questions ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the component specified in update=":form:messages" everytime click the checkbox. I guess "messages" ID belongs to a container where the datatable is in. If it is not right, i don't understend why the databled gets updated. If it is right, just delete the update attribute or update something that does not contain the datatable inside.